# Identity field not sequential

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database, which contains around 20 tables. I just saw that one of them that the identity field (primary key) is incrementing by 1 for a while and at certain point it jumps with a random number. This happens at two places. First with 1029 and then with 997. They are not related to deleted records or using the CHECKIDENT RESEED.

Any ideas how can I check what causes it?

Comment: IDENTITY will increment if you stage a transaction, but don't commit it.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012339/windows-azure-sql-database-identity-auto-increment-column-skips-values) may help. See, you can get into the sequence gap trouble on SQL Server 2012, especially if hosted by Azure.

Comment: Thanks Orzen! I am glad I am not the only one (not going crazy). I hope MS addresses it soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a transaction that inserts records, but the transaction is rolled back the identity seed still increments.  Maybe you had some instances where something failed and was rolled back?

Comment: I realize that and I am sure there were no 1029 and 997 failures in a row. The DB is used only by my laptop as it is a test DB. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Azure database the identity field can increment when the database replicates.