# Field sudden increase

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table in EntityFramework that has a field named by ID,
this field is primary key and is Identity.
when  i add records into this table, this field value increases per recor, after adding several records, this value suddenly increases
For example, increased from 90 in 1010
While no transaction has been unsuccessful.
what is the problem?

Comment: This field has this property: [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGenerated
           (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Comment: Make sure the seed for your field is set to just 1.

Comment: @Hanlet Escaño yes is set to 1

Comment: How do you add the records? Show us some code pls.

Comment: for example : dbContext.TableName.add(object); and then : dbcontext.SaveChanges()

Comment: I just wanted to see more _how_ you actually implement it (is it inside a loop for example).

Comment: oh, no. Records simply added to table in a transaction, with any loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113829/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-deve-loper).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure SQL this can just happen. We had it happen a few times. It is just the nature of how Azure sql works.

See this question [Windows Azure SQL Database - Identity Auto increment column skips values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012339/windows-azure-sql-database-identity-auto-increment-column-skips-values) it goes into a detailed explanation for a case very similar to yours