# SQL crazy jumping Identity Seed

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

[image]

I am using a simply add method from entity framework, this making me concerned, but i want to know if have any way to evade this jump, maybe this occur when server restart, I am not sure.

Comment: What's the query you're using to get those result sets?  Is it `SELECT id_User FROM Table1 ORDER BY id_User DESC`?

Comment: Also what is the column definition?

Comment: I don't know about EF, but other ORM's reserve a block of IDENTITY values to use locally on the client when performing their operations.  If they never get used then you'll see these kind of jumps in the IDENTITY values.  I would imagine EF could do this as well.  But it looks like id_User is not an INT column if these results are all from the same table.

Comment: This is a known issue in SQL Server 2012 when restarting the service. If it actually is causing you a real problem (can't really see how it would) see the Connect item linked in the possible dupe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin mentioned, this is a known (nasty!) issue since SQL Server 2012, which gave me headaches. If your solution depends on the id's i suggest you use the in SQL Server 2012 newly introduced [Sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx) mechanism. But be aware that this feature is not available in SQL Azure.