# Why does the SQL Server auto increment jump by 2 for each row?

Tags: sql-server, database, auto-increment

**Edit:** I believe it is not a duplicate since I tried all the solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is) and none of them is working, so it is probably another issue. Also, because in all of the existing questions, the jump is by 1000, but here it is by 2. Also, because it did not happened after restarting SQL Server.

---

I created an `ID` column and set it as shown in this image:

[image]

But when I try to insert data to the table, the id jumps by 2:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect your insert code has a bug (perhaps it is performing two inserts and rolling one back or deleting it).

Comment: Hey, Aaron. I didn't use any code for the insertion, only the SQL Server Management tools for insertion...

Comment: Like `Edit Top 200 Rows`? Stop doing that. I bet the problem goes away if you write proper `INSERT` statements in a query window. (Also, verify that the table doesn't have a trigger.)