# SQLServer - Primary Key jump sequence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I use SQlServer 2014 Express, in many table I use the classical primary key with this setting:

[image]

After some classical insert by sql I have a jump in ID number.

[image]

I use SQL Server for many years but I have never had this.
Can you tell me why this happens?

Comment: **[identity increment is jumping in sql server database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database)** It is a [feature](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity) :) Could we close it as duplicate or do you need additional assistance?

Comment: @lad2025 Thank you, you can mark as duplicated