# ID is increase thousand by thousand in my database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]

I'm working on my Asp.Net MVC project.  I'm using SQL Server Managment Studio. Why BrandId increase thousand by thousand?

Comment: How does BrandId get a value as each row is inserted?

Comment: Is this database in Azure?

Comment: @jrummell Database isn't in Azure.

Comment: A really big transaction was rolled back?  Showing us the table definition would help (Right click table > Script Table As > Create to > clipboard).

Comment: Does the BrandId column have an identity specification?

Comment: Insert a bunch more records and see what happens.  If it is cyclical like that, its probably how the IDENTITY/TRIGGER was configured.  If it run sequentially with no problems, something probably got deleted or rolled back.

Comment: I've had this before when using migrations. Never got to the bottom of the issue, so I'll be interested to see if anyone has a solution / reason.

Comment: @RandyMinder I set one by one to Identity Specification. Insert the row while ID  increase automatically

Comment: do you using entity framework?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway  I set one by one to Identity Specification. Insert the row while ID increase automatically.

Comment: @NazmulHasan Yes, I'm using Entity Framewok

Comment: do you deleted anything from first  row?

Answer (score 1):

Since `BrandId` is an identity column, there are a few things that could cause what you're seeing.

1. Someone could have changed the seed increment to 1000.
2. Someone could have inserted large batches of rows and then rolled them back in a transaction. In this case, the increment doesn't get rolled back (I don't think).
3. Someone could have turned off (or overrode) the Identity property, manually inserted rows with those values and then turned Identity back on.

Given the values go from 1005 to 2002, it doesn't seem as likely the increment was changed to 1000. Option 2 or 3 seems more likely.

Comment: none of the above, know bug(or feature) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database