# Can SQL Server have an identity column based on another column

Tags: sql-server

Can SQL Server have an identity column based on another column?

I have a table design like this

```
Audit 
AuditId
CompanyId
```

Everything in the system is audited, and the table can be multi tenant, thus the `CompanyId`.

In the context of an audit, people like to see a sequential sequence of events and due to the multi tenant nature, the identity will skip numbers like this.

1. Company1 User logged in
2. Company1 User logged out
3. Company1 User logged in
4. Company9 User logged in
5. Company1 User logged out
6. Company9 User logged out

I would ideally keep `AuditId` as a normal identity but wish to have a secondary identity column that is unique to `CompanyId`.

Is this possible in SQL Server, or do I need to do it in code?

Comment: there can be only one identity column in a table

Comment: "In the context of an audit, people like to see a sequential sequence of events" - yes, they do. But if that's what you need (a sequence with *no gaps*), then `IDENTITY` is the wrong tool to start with. See e.g. the bold section at the bottom of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14146237/15498) (and also, just look at the question :-))

Comment: @AksheyBhat I'd accept that if you post it as an answer

Comment: It looks like XY problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server can't have an identity column based on another column because there can be only one identity column in a table.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the companyAuditId populated by an insert trigger. It would be defined as int, but on insert the trigger will

```
Create trigger trAuditI for insert 

        UPDATE audit
     SET CompanyAuditId = max(companyAuditId) 

    where companyId
        = Inserted.CompanyId
```

Comment: This trigger is broken. Triggers fire once per statement, `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows (or no rows).