# SQL Server primary key identity large gap between records

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am using Azure SQL Server and have a user table with an auto incrementing identity column.  The identity ID has jumped from 4800 to 12000 to 52000 in just the last three inserts.  I understand there can be gaps, but why such a large jump?  Is this something I need to fix?

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database

Comment: This is helpful.  Thanks.