# I have an error in auto increment

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I made a small software with C#. When I add a new record auto-increment doesn't work well like records are **1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6**, then it should be **7** but it goes to **1025, 1026, 1027**, then again it goes to **2035, 2036, 2037** it doesn't work well.

Insert code:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
mycon.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Bill (Date, Time, Cashier, Amount, Patient) values('" + DateTime.Now + "','" + date.ToString("hh:mm") + "','" + "Ahmad" + "'," + lbltotaldu.Text + ",'" + txtpatient.Text + "')", mycon);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

mycon.Close();
```

Comment: Have you restarted your SQL Service or your server ?

Comment: @user3185569 yes i restart my server

Comment: SQL server does not store data in the order it is inserted.  SQL uses a hash.  So when you query the database to get data in a particular order you need to use an Order By.

Comment: was the database previously used ?

Comment: looking in to the `ORDER BY` command

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: It's not an **error** - it's just the way it works in SQL Server 2012 and newer. See this other SO question for a great explanation my Martin Smith: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database