# How to reset Identity column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I created a table `Tbl_Category` with an identity column (2001,1) and inserted four records into the table. Up to four rows, it worked fine, when I'm trying to insert a 5th row now, the identity column jumps to a value of 3005. The identity column (3001,1) was assigned to another table `Tbl_Subcategory` in the same database.

Table structure:

[image]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14146237/3540365

Comment: Note: if, for whatever reason, you _really_ needed to reset the identity to a certain value you could use something like `dbcc checkident('myTable', reseed, X)` where X is the number you wish to reset to.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can go into the table by right clicking on it and then pressing Design. Then in there mark the row you want to remove the identity from and at the bottom of your screen look for "Identity Specification". Then click that and double click to change the "Yes" to a "No".