# Id's jumping up 1000 every time I build my app and insert a new record

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm building a basic CRUD page following beginner asp.net-core-mvc/ef-core tutorials

I've been noticing every time I rebuild and create a new record through my mvc site my Id's jump up 1000

Example, currently the id's for my first few rows are:

- 1, 2, 1002, 1003, 1004, 2002, 2003, 3002, 3003, 4002, 5002

How do I stop this? I've never seen this behavior before. From some googling it seems to be a sql 2012 issue however I'm not using sql 2012.

I'm using mssqllocaldb, everything's updated and I have SSMS2014 installed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identity increment is jumping in SQL Server database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database)

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8252

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you have installed the `SSMS 2014`, it doesn't install the `2014 local db` instance. It still can be a `SQL 2012 local DB`.  So my advice is to uninstall all old components and install the latest `local db 2016` and `SSMS 2016`.  Both are **free**.

**Here are the links :**

[**SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx)

[**SSMS 2016**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)

**Additional Note :**

Yes this is a bug on the `SQL server 2012`.You can see it here :

[**Failover or Restart Results in Reseed of Identity**](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity)

**Workarounds :**

If you need the Workarounds see the `Workarounds` tab on the above link.

[image]

**Permanent solution :**

If you need a permanent solution, you can use a higher version of SQL server. Like `SQL server 2014` or `2016`.You can select `Free community editions` of those.

Comment: I'm not using SQL 2012. I'm using mssqllocaldb. I'm not sure what determines the version of localdb, but i have Sql Data Tools fully updated and Sql Management Studio 2014 installed, so my mssqllocaldb should be using newer than 2012

Comment: what is the version of `mssqllocaldb` ?

Comment: how do i check the version?

Comment: please see this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh215237.aspx

Comment: Finally got it thanks. Yes the root cause was SQL 2012 even though I already had 2014/2016 installed. Ended up having to manually uninstall all references to sql 2012 and do a repair of sql 2016 and a repair of VS2015 before it worked.

Comment: WHen I try to uninstall SQL Server 2012 Native Client, it says SQL Server 2016 LocalDB depends on it. :( Uninstall Anyway? I don't have SQL 2012 LocalDB at all, would this still be the root cause in my case?