# SQL Server Database Identity Columns value Jumping

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, web-hosting

I am hosting my **Database** on [SmarterASP.net](http://www.SmarterASP.net).

**It is the third time** i got an unbelievable error from this database
the matter is that i have more than (50) tables that has identity column

it is the third time that **all of this identity columns skipped a (2000 , 1000 or 993) value at the same time without doing any thing wrong from the user i'am sure.**

i have been saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database) and i submitted a ticket for **the hosting teqnical support** and this is their reply

[image]

**Note**, i am using :

1. ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.5)
2. SQL Server 2014
3. ADO.NET with C#

Comment: Gaps in an identity are expected and perfectly normal. Even if the identity didn't jump when the service restarts you would still get gaps when rows are deleted. Why is a gap such a big deal anyway? Identity values are just a number, it shouldn't matter if they are in perfect alignment.

Comment: @SeanLange, it is not a problem for me as **a developer**, it is a big problem **for the customer** when he has reached the **10000 invoice** but actually he had **only 6000 invoice** and so on for **customer ID**.

Comment: Then you should use a sequence instead of an identity.