# SQL Server table jumping numbers on auto increment id's

Tags: sql-server

In doing some testing on a new table in my SQL Server database, I noticed the auto-incremented id's were not sequential, which I know can be the case. BUT, as you can see from the picture below, after a dozen or so entries, the id field is up to using 10005!. Why is the id jumping higher like that? Is there any way to control that? Otherwise I can envision 20 digit id numbers in the future which isn't preferred.

[image: Table view]

Comment: one way is `row_number()` you could use explicitly assign ranking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database