# Why Sql Server SELECT does not return all entries?

Tags: sql-server

Ok. I completely rewrote my question.

**Database table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IntegrationCommandLog](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Content] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [OrderingKey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NULL,
    [Topic] [nvarchar](13) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_IntegrationCommandLog] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IntegrationCommandLog_OrderingKey] ON [dbo].[IntegrationCommandLog]
(
    [OrderingKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Reproducer. Run release without attached debugger is required**

Required packages:

```
Install-Package Dapper
Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient
```

Code:

```
using Dapper;
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string Sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.IntegrationCommandLog WHERE OrderingKey > @OrderingKey ORDER BY OrderingKey";
        private const string cs = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => Query());

            var tasks = new Task[200];
            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; ++i)
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => Insert());

            while (true)
            {
                int j = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
                tasks[j] = Task.Run(() => Insert());
            }
        }

        private async static Task Query()
        {
            long last = -1;
            var connection = new SqlConnection(cs);
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            while (true)
            {
                var entries = await connection.QueryAsync<IntegrationLogEntry>(Sql, new { OrderingKey = last });

                Console.WriteLine(entries.Count());
                if (entries.Any())
                {
                    last = entries.Aggregate((e1, e2) =>
                    {
                        if (e1.OrderingKey + 1 != e2.OrderingKey)
                            Console.WriteLine($"Sequence violation {e1.OrderingKey} {e2.OrderingKey}");

                        return e2;
                    }).OrderingKey;
                }
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Insert()
        {
            string sql = @"SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[IntegrationCommandLog] ([Id], [Content], [Topic])
VALUES ( @Id, @Content, @Topic);
SELECT [OrderingKey], [RowVersion]
FROM [dbo].[IntegrationCommandLog]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = @Id";

            var content = new string('a', 1000);
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, new { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Content = content, Topic = "SomeTopic" });
            }
        }
    }

    public class IntegrationLogEntry
    {
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }
        public string Content { get; private set; }
        public string Topic { get; private set; }
        public long OrderingKey { get; private set; }
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Make sure there are no gaps**

```
SELECT top 100 * FROM (SELECT *, rowid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderingKey) FROM [dbo].[IntegrationCommandLog]) l1
JOIN (SELECT *, rowid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderingKey) FROM [dbo].[IntegrationCommandLog]) l2 on l1.rowid + 1 = l2.rowid
WHERE l1.OrderingKey + 1 != l2.OrderingKey
```

**Output**

[image: Console output]

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64)   Oct 28 2016 18:17:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

**Questions:**

1. Why the query does not return all entries?
2. How to get correct list of entries?

Comment: ok, what values do you see for @Prev and @After?  The query has "AND OrderingKey > @OrderingKey" so we should expect to have various Keys,  and the testing signals error when "!= " not equal...

Comment: I added .net poco class which represents the query result in my app code. OrderingKey is long.

Comment: Last error contains two gaps 1:@prev=17198 @after=17213 2:@prev=17214 @after=17218

Comment: Can there be later changes to the topic?  It is the only other thing in the Where.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identity increment is jumping in SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database)

Comment: Checked it twice. No changing code, no update statements in a profiler. Removed topic from where clause but problem still exists.

Comment: "My log contains error messages" **What messages?** Show us what the error was.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I think the OP is referring to the log record bring written `Log.Error("Sequence violation...`, not an actual error being emitted.

Comment: It could be a race condition, a record not committed but where the is has been assigned from the cach of numbers. If you want more help you will have to provide an [mcve].

Comment: Any analysis via SMSS of the rows with OrderingKey   2:@prev=17214 @after=17218   both ends and inbetween rows?  What might be special about these?  Present in SMSS, absent in separate dedicated thread? Both pointing at same instance and db? Row locks/page locks?

Answer (score 0):

e1.OrderingKey + 1 != e2.OrderingKey tests that e2 is only 1 higher than the previous key.  That isn't guaranteed by the database.

There are many things that will cause non-consecutive IDENTITY: (not forgetting deletes)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017

> Consecutive values within a transaction – A transaction inserting
>   multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows
>   because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values
>   must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock
>   on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.
>
> Consecutive values after server restart or other failures – SQL Server might cache
>   identity values for performance reasons and some of the assigned
>   values can be lost during a database failure or server restart. This
>   can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert. If gaps are not
>   acceptable then the application should use its own mechanism to
>   generate key values. Using a sequence generator with the NOCACHE
>   option can limit the gaps to transactions that are never committed.
>
> Reuse of values – For a given identity property with specific
>   seed/increment, the identity values are not reused by the engine. If a
>   particular insert statement fails or if the insert statement is rolled
>   back then the consumed identity values are lost and will not be
>   generated again. This can result in gaps when the subsequent identity
>   values are generated.

Comment: Does it mean that sql server can fill gaps in the sequence later after the query was executed? I dont think this is possible.

Comment: I checked every error message. I'm not able to find any gap

Comment: I understand that there may be gaps, but that is not the case. This check was added to track down why I lose messages