# Auto-increment value does NOT gradually increasing

Tags: sql, sql-server, localdb

Although there are no deleted rows or any rollback processes, the numbering is NOT increasing regularly, why?

[image]

The `[id]` column is auto increment by 1.

[image]

Comment: Gaps are to be expected.  Take a peek at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column

Comment: Just to add, look at the REMARKS section  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: [Identity increment is jumping in SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database)

Comment: Gaps are to be expected, but anyway, in your sample dataset, are you actually ordering by `id`?