# How to remove gaps due the jump of identity column in SQL Server 2017?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, sql-server-2017, ef-core-3.1

I use SQL Server with ASP.NET Core and EF Core. After each record is added, the identity column's value jumps about by 1000 and creates a gap between current row and the last previously added row.

Questions

- Is there any way to prevent this?
- How to delete those gaps that have been created before?
- If I use GUID for key columns to prevent that issue, is there a problem (performance or each other problem)?
- Is it way on the server side that with EF Core could handle it (each some way)?

Thank you in advance for your helps...

Comment: You don't remove the gaps. They are there by design; the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) tells you this. If you don't want gaps, then `IDENTITY` is not what you want. Either way, you're asking 4 questions here, not 1, and this is therefore too broad.

Comment: Yes, GUID's as clustering index keys [are **horrible** in terms of performance](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/) ......

Comment: See this [other SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database) for answers to your other questions

Comment: @marc_s I don't think that's completely relevant anymore. Especially with `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`. That article *is* 11 years old now.

Comment: @Larnu: yes, using `newsequentialid()` can mitigate the negative effects *a bit* - but all the other points (like wasting space due to 4x bigger key size) are still **absolutely valid** - to this day

Comment: True on  the size, but I just see people just saying "guids are bad" far too often, and the main reason being that they are "random" and so poor clustered index choices. It's not completely slame dunk like is was 15 years ago. (But then people are still using 30 year old implicit Join syntax and data types like `image` and `text`in new development work, so why should I expect them to change *now*. )

Comment: In addition to this, the choice of guid as a key is not usually because it's "right or wrong" from a database point of view, but rather because this way the client can generate the auto-key before hitting the database. This is seen as useful for straightforward client-server, and arguably even more useful with distributed databases or distributed systems, and *definitely* useful when it comes to generating correlation id's for messages between systems. Of course, EF just uses `newsequentialid`, which is cheating. .net core has a native method for this. Still, I don't like the size of them.

Answer (score 3):

For the reason for 1000-value gaps, see [Aaron Bertrand's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column)

It doesn't really make sense to "want" to delete the gaps. The content of an identity column contains no semantic information. It correlates to nothing "in the world" outside the database. The gaps are as meaningless as the values themselves.

I don't see how a `uniqueidentifier` would "prevent" that issue. A uniqueidentifier may be "meaningfully" sortable (if you use `newsequentialid()`), but there's no sense in which any particular value is "one more" than a previous value.

You can certainly try to build your own key generating algorithm that does not produce gaps, but you will run into concurrency issues (also mentioned by Mr Bertrand).

Answer (score 0):

workaround trick:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TGR_Transaction_Identity_Fix 
    ON [dbo].[TBL_Transaction] 
    FOR INSERT 
  AS 
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @RESEEDVAL INT
    SELECT @RESEEDVAL = MAX(TransactionId) FROM [dbo].[TBL_Transaction] 
    DBCC CHECKIDENT([TBL_Transaction], RESEED, @RESEEDVAL)
  END
```

this triger will reset identity on each insert