# Id identity int doesn't start from 1?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server Management Studio I created several tables and in id I used `identity(1,1)` with `constraint primary key clustered Id asc`. When I was insert values in tables and after that I saw the column with id in every table starting with another number like 8, 5, 9 etc, but not with 1 as it should be. I didn't have this problem before. Is it possible because first I connected tables with foreign key and after that I started to insert values? Here is the code:

```
create table [dbo].[Semester]
(
     [Id] [int] identity(1,1) not null,
     [Semester] [tinyint] null,
     [StartDay] [date] not null,
     [EndDate] [date] not null,

     constraint [PK_Semester] 
         primary key clustered ([Id] asc)
)
go

insert into [dbo].[Subject] ([Name], [Days])
values ('Intro in programming', 20)
```

and the result is:

|  | Id | Name | Days | SemesterId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | Intro in programming | 20 | null |

I don't have insert value  in `SemesterId` because in that table like in every tables is the same problem and have exception doesn't match with `Id` in Semester table with `SemesterId`, because in Semester table column `Id` is 6 and whenever I delete them and re-create them, `Id`'s has difference numbers, but not start from 1 and doesn't ascending in order.

Comment: The table that your `INSERT` has as target isn't the one the `CREATE` is from.

Comment: If you delete records the numbers aren't reused. And they usually don't need to and shouldn't do that either. The only thing `identity(1,1)` guarantees is that each value is unique. And that's the only important thing. So you shouldn't worry about that. It's all OK.

Comment: The reason Id is jumping is likely related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database

Comment: You should'n care about it. If you do, you shouldn't use an Identity column. Read more: https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/sql-servers-identity-column-misconceptions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use command below to see what is current seed of your table identity value:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('Subject');
```

with command below you can reseed your identity value if you have no data in the table otherwise there are some exceptions ( [Read Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', RESEED, new_value);
```

In your case I assume you have inserted some rows and then you have deleted , you can use

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

to truncate table as well as reset the seed identiry

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks  a lot. First I deleted every rows, then DBCC CHECKIDENT('Semester', RESEED, 0) and after that, insert values in table.

Comment: great ,  please accept this answer as an answer to help community ,

Answer (score 1):

When you send an `INSERT` query to the SQL Server, the SQL Server generates an `ID` for this query. If the query is successful, you will see that `ID` you assigned in the table. If the query fails, it will not save the same `ID` for another query. SQL Server generates a new `ID` on the next query.

*Namely,*

You probably made incorrect entries in column '**SemesterId**' of table **'Subject'**. As far as I know there is no problem. `IDENTITY` columns increase the value  even if the `INSERT` to table  is not performed. But If you say I want to see sequentially, you set the `IDENTITY` property to -No-, in this case you need to assign an `ID` for each record. This is a bit of a problem for tables with many records.