# How to reset identity column after server restart in entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, identity

I'm using the code first approach in entity framework to create my database and I have a table as follows:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StrToGuidConverter))]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }= Guid.NewGuid(); 
  
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int userFriendly { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = "";

    public string Location { get; set; } = "";

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = "";

}
```

where the `userFriendly` attribute is just a way of representing IDs that starts from 1

I'm having trouble because the `userFriendly` values goes like this:
`{1,2,3,4,1004,1005,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,3005}`

where it should actually be increment by only one.

I've searched online and found that it maybe happening when the SQL server restart and I found a [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62151/what-could-cause-an-auto-increment-primary-key-to-skip-numbers) that suggest to reset the identity when the server restarts as follows:

```
USE [master]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ResetOrderIdentityAfterRestart]
AS
BEGIN

begin TRAN
    declare @id int = 0
    SELECT @id =  MAX(id) FROM [DatabaseName].dbo.[TableName]
    --print @id
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[DatabaseName].dbo.[TableName]', reseed, @id)
Commit

END
```

I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database) which could be viewed as a related question but it doesn't really answer my question

Because what I was  wondering in fact was how to do the same in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146148/identity-increment-is-jumping-in-sql-server-database) in entity framework and how can I call this code every time the server restart without altering any code that is generated upon adding migration since I'm using code first approach?

Comment: Maybe you should look into why your server needs so much restarting instead

Comment: I think you are putting too much importance on the value of an identity. Who cares if there are gaps? Gaps are going to happen when rows are deleted.

Comment: I don't care about the gaps if they're caused by deleting rows but that isn't what's happening because the gaps are there when in fact I didn't delete any row 
In addition, as I mentioned in my question I'm using the identity as a user friendly id for the end user to use instead of long GUID @SeanLange

Comment: @siba36 but who cares what the value is? You are putting way too much importance on an arbitrary value.

Comment: it is not arbitrary it refers to how many record have been added and that's what I'm trying to do which is that I want to assosiate an integer number which each company that indicate how many company have been added so far so I can refer to each company by its number @SeanLange

Comment: It is actually arbitrary, you are assigning value to it beyond the ability of the construct. You shouldn't use an identity for this. That is not what it does. It will increment for every insert attempt. Yes, attempt. If an insert fails the identity will still increment. It will also skip numbers when the sql server is restarted. If you really want this level of control you should instead use a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @siba36 If you would like to have closer IDs as they tend to get too big, then you can try SQL: `ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION  SET IDENTITY_CACHE = OFF` (taken from the article above). But I think that a server which often reboots is a bigger and unacceptable problem.