# Rolling back Default Constraint causes IDENTITY gap of 10000. Why is that?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Steps are as so:

- begin transaction
- add constraint
- insert
- rollback

And when I run this:

```
SELECT * FROM Champ   -- last ID at 30014

BEGIN TRANSACTION

ALTER TABLE Champ 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Champ_NumWins DEFAULT 0 FOR NumWins

INSERT INTO Champ(Name, DateOfBirth)
VALUES('TestDummy', '1911/12/11')

ROLLBACK

INSERT INTO Champ(Name, DateOfBirth)
VALUES('TestDummy', '1911/12/11')

SELECT * FROM Champ    -- last ID now 40015
```

Shows an immediate gap in the Identity column of 10,000. This does not happen if I do not insert within the transaction (no gap), nor if I do not add the constraint (gap of only 1).

Table is initially defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Champ]
(
    [ChampID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreateTSO] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [NumWins] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Champ] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Champ_CreateTSO] DEFAULT (SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) FOR [CreateTSO]
```

I'm using SQL Server 2017. Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: apologies I miss read question. I have voted to reopen. Post post the EXACT code to reproduce the problem, including your table definition. Identity gaps after rollback is well known and documented.

Comment: I can verify the behaviour exactly you have described (SQL Server 2019). That said, relying on contiguous identity Ids as surrogates is wrong.  If you require no gaps, using SEQUENCES with NOCACHE instead. The jump of 10000 is likely due to some batching optimisations, or it could even be an edge case bug (I mean who creates a constraint within a transaction.....

Comment: 300014 -> 40015? Or is it 30014 -> 40015 or 300014 -> 400015? What happens if you add an `ORDER BY` to the `SELECT` queries - `select top 10 * from Champ order by ChampID desc`. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the result order is indeterminant and the top and tail of the query results might not represent the first and last `ChampID` values.

Comment: Maybe it's 10000 for bigint and 1000 for INT. Looks strange though, I'd say it's a bug, normally this gap only happens on server restart

Comment: Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/Gv-ZygeW

Comment: I believe it only happens in the case where the transaction that gets rolled back included both DDL to alter the table and DML to invoke identity in the same table. If you move the first insert outside the transaction, the gap doesn't occur.

Comment: (So then the question becomes, why are you mixing DDL and DML inside the same transaction?)

Comment: @TN It should have been 30014 , not 300014. I've corrected that.  As per siggemannen yes it appears that when the identity is just an INT then the jump is 1000 (tested with a new table, "LilChamp").  And to Aaron Bertrand, also confirmed your suspicions--that if I added a column instead of a constrain the results are the same.  In any case, this is just a toy database specifically for playing with SQL